# распределение значений в столбце pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, pandas

Имеется датафрейм:

```
id      date     score
12    15.05.19     4
34    10.04.19     3
17    02.06.19     7
19    30.07.19     5
25    28.05.19     6
```

имеется список ответственных лиц:

```
spisok = ['Ivanov', 'Petrov', 'Sidorov']
```

Хочу в результате получить - добавить в датафрейм колонку с ответственными лицами:

```
id      date     score   in_charge
12    15.05.19     4      Ivanov
34    10.04.19     3      Petrov
17    02.06.19     7      Sidorov
19    30.07.19     5      Ivanov
25    28.05.19     6      Petrov
```

Написал функцию, но не могу ее применить:

```
def an_distr(df, spisok):


    count = len(df)
    while count >= 0:
        for el in spisok:
            return el
            count = count - 1

df['in_charge'] = an_distr(df, spisok)
```

выдает ошибку

> TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция неправильно работает хотя бы потому, что после

```
return el
```

функция вернёт значение и последующий код выполняться не будет.

Пришло на ум вот такое решение, что называется "в лоб":

```
# Формируем список, который будет добавлен в качестве столбца
s = [spisok[i % len(spisok)] for i in range(len(df))]

df['in_charge'] = s

>>> df
id      date  score in_charge
12  15.05.19      4    Ivanov
34  10.04.19      3    Petrov
17  02.06.19      7   Sidorov
19  30.07.19      5    Ivanov
25  28.05.19      6    Petrov
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваше решение помогло очень!